# Selenium tests are getting stuck at alternate test case, shows URL and blank page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, geckodriver

Selenium tests are getting stuck begining of test case, only shows URL and blank page. If I click refresh manually or adding multiple refresh in code, it starts again and loads page. Here in below example test2 and test4 always fails with TimeoutException. test3 and test4 works due to new navigate works as refresh. I tried to increase wait time, but it works with refresh only. is there any other alternative option? I am trying to find out root cause.
Build info: version: '3.7.0'
browserName: firefox, 
browserVersion: 68.8.0, 
moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0,

```
@Before
public void before() {
      browser.navigate().to(Url);
      browser.navigate().refresh(); // sometimes works or needs extra refresh
      wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(<<ID>>));
    }
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    ///some code
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    //some code
}

@Test
public void test3() {
   //some code
}

@Test
public void test4() {
    //some code
}

@Test
public void test5() {
    //some code
}
```

}

Comment: You may want to read this post (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-compatible-Selenium-version-for-Firefox-57-0-4). Looks like you're using an older version of `Selenium` and possibly an older version of the `geckodriver`. You should be using the newest version of both if you want to support that version of Firefox. As brower versions change, you need to use newer versions of Selenium and the drivers to support them.

Comment: I am using latest version of Graphene:2.3.2 http://arquillian.org/modules/graphene-extension/, latest:geckodriver:0.26.0, latest firefox available on rhel: 68.8.0